# remote: Repository not found. GitHub Action

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am currently developing pipelines using GitHub action and in this process I am trying to push code from the template branch of repos A to the dev branch of repos B using a GitHub Action workflow.

For this, I used the following code:

```
          git config user.email "${{ github.event.inputs.email }}"
          git config user.name "${{ github.event.inputs.user }}"
          git remote -v
          git remote add origin2 https://${{ github.event.inputs.TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ github.event.inputs.org }}/${{ github.event.inputs.repos }}.git
          git remote -v
          git pull
          git checkout template
          git push -f origin2 template:${{ env.dev }}
```

As you can see I fully parameterize the code to make it dynamic.

The problem is that once this code is executed, the GitHub Action console gives me the following error:

[image]

The `snowflakeTestRepos` repository does however exist in the `samyKheznadji` organization.

I don't understand why it doesn't work knowing that when I run it locally it works.

Thanks for your help :)

I tried to create the remote origin2 with a Personal Access Token with full access. The repository is private.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure your token is invalid.

There are the posibilities:

- You don't sent token
- You sent token but in invalid name
- You sent invalid/expired token

Comment: My Personal Access Token is good for 2 reasons:

1. I also use it to clone repos and it works

2. The same code (without GitHub parameters) executed locally works.

3. To remove any doubt I just recreated a PAT and it still doesn't work ^^